# DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator returns a phone number

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, carrier

I'm using DeviceNetworkInformation.CellularMobileOperator() in my application to get the carrier information from mobiles phones, as explained on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.cellularmobileoperator%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

A user has reported to me that the information he returned was a phone number.

I'm wondering if anybody else has got this bug ? It seems like a critical flaw in the Windows Phone SDK.

Comment: Can you inquire the user what phone (brand & model) is he using? And what OS version?

Comment: It's a Samsung Omnia with Mango.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function relies solely on the information the carrier provides. I used it on several phones in the US and in all cases I get the carrier name (e.g. AT&T). Apparently, some carriers set their identifier as the user phone number. This is **not an SDK flaw**, but rather a carrier misjudgment.